# Objective c variable assignment not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to put the function parameters into an array and I can not figure this out for the life of me. labelPoi is an object class that contains imageLocationX, imageLocationY, and name. I am trying to assign values found in one ViewController to values in another ViewController and it is not working for me.

This is in my First ViewController

```
PointOfInterest.imageLocationX = (((([self getDegreesFromRadians:angle_horizontal] / [self getDegreesFromRadians:FOV_Horizontal]))) *1024);
        PointOfInterest.imageLocationY = ((1-(([self getDegreesFromRadians:angle_to_bottom_of_view] / [self getDegreesFromRadians:FOV_Vertical])))*576);

PictureViewController *newlabel = [[PictureViewController alloc] display:PointOfInterest.imageLocationX andY:PointOfInterest.imageLocationY withName:PointOfInterest.name];
```

And this is in my second ViewController (PictureViewController)

```
- (id)display:(double)imageXX andY:(double)imageYY withName:(NSString *)namee{
NSLog(@"%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
NSLog(@"imageX: %f",imageXX);
NSLog(@"imageY: %f", imageYY);
NSLog(@"name: %@", namee);

labelPoi.imageLocationX = imageXX;
labelPoi.imageLocationY = imageYY;
labelPoi.name = name;
[transfer addObject:labelPoi];
NSLog(@"label.x: %f should be: %f", labelPoi.imageLocationX, imageXX);
NSLog(@"label.y: %f should be: %f", labelPoi.imageLocationY, imageYY);
NSLog(@"label.name: %@ should be: %@",labelPoi.name,namee);

return self;
```

}

And this is the output:

```
2013-07-18 14:21:14.731 AR_UAV_App[10641:11303] %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
2013-07-18 14:21:14.731 AR_UAV_App[10641:11303] imageX: 224.485718
2013-07-18 14:21:14.731 AR_UAV_App[10641:11303] imageY: 116.353401
2013-07-18 14:21:14.731 AR_UAV_App[10641:11303] name: Beutel Student Health Center
2013-07-18 14:21:14.731 AR_UAV_App[10641:11303] label.x 0.000000
2013-07-18 14:21:14.731 AR_UAV_App[10641:11303] label.y 0.000000 should be 116.353401
2013-07-18 14:33:29.882 AR_UAV_App[10700:11303] label.name: (null) should be: Beutel Student Health Center#############################################################
```

Why does

```
NSLog(@"label.x: %f should be: %f", labelPoi.imageLocationX, imageXX);
```

output 0.00000?

EDIT:
This is my Poi class which is labelPoi

```
#import "Poi.h"

@implementation Poi
@synthesize longitude;
@synthesize latitude;
@synthesize name;
@synthesize x;
@synthesize y;
@synthesize distance;
@synthesize isVisibleToCamera;

-(id)initWithLatitude:(double)lat AtLongitude:(double)lon withName:(NSString *)name{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.latitude = lat;
        self.longitude = lon;
        self.name = name;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Is `labelPoi` `nil`? You need to create the object first with `alloc` and `init`.

Comment: Why did you remove the code? This isn't answerable at all without some code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to allocate and initialize `labelPOI`. It is `nil`, and trying to access a property on, or send a message to, `nil` does nothing.